# Xcode : Applescript app

Tags: xcode, applescript

I didn't did an Applescript app on Xcode from ages,

here is my code

```
script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value
    property myTextField : missing value

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_


    on myButton_(sender)
       -- AppleScript 
    end myButton_

    on saveNote_(sender)
    -- AppleScript 
    ​end saveNote_


end script
```

but I have this error :

/AppDelegate.applescript:32: error: Expected “end” but found unknown token. (-2741)
Command /usr/bin/osacompile failed with exit code 1

Can you help me here?

PS here is the AppleScript

```
to getInputByClass2(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return input
end getInputByClass2
getInputByClass2("field type-string field-DATAID", 0)
set theText to Unicode text
set theSource to getInputByClass2("field type-string field-DATAID", 0)
property leftEdge : "class=\"value\">"
property rightEdge : "</span>"
set saveTID to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to leftEdge
set classValue to text item 2 of theSource
set text item delimiters to rightEdge
set theDATAID to text item 1 of classValue
set text item delimiters to saveTID
theDATAID
```

here is the result on xcode

[image: http://s33.postimg.org/9nmzj3m7v/Screen_Shot_2016_05_27_at_18_29_44.jpg]

Comment: So it's seems to come from  :    on saveNote_(sender)
    -- AppleScript 
    ​end saveNote_

Answer (score 0):

You're using the reserved word `date` as a variable name which is not allowed. To avoid that use `aDate` or `theDate` or something meaningful compound like `startDate`.

Consider that you are actually using none of the variables at the end of the sections and most of the code is redundant and could be reduced with a repeat loop.

Comment: Yes but even if I put the first part only, (script updated) I still have an error. The AppleScript it actually only geting all the data I want from a website and copy in the clipboard.  or should I get Xcode to call an external script to get the clipboard ? I just want this past in a textfiled.

Comment: The code doesn't copy anything to the clipboard. It just recalls the variable `theDATAID` at the end

Comment: Sorry I mean the full script

Comment: The snippet compiles flawlessly.